# How to bookmark lines of code in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, bookmarks

In Matlab I can bookmark lines of code and cycle through my bookmarks with, I think it was F12.

Very handy! Can I do something similar in Rstudio?

Comment: I know you can for Rshiny, but I don't know if such thing exist for classic R scripts

Comment: Is RShiny something on top of Rstudio or does it replace it?

Comment: RShiny is a way to develop interactive-web-app with R, sorry if i created any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using additional add-ons you can use hashtags #### COMMENT #### or left click next to the linenumber to set a bookmark to this line.[image: Exmaple Here]

Answer (score 3):

```
[#BOOKMARK TITLE====]
```

Thats how I do it.  Make sure you use four equal signs else it won't work.  Bookmarks then shows up in the scroll box at the bottom of the code window to the left.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
# one hash and four (or more) hashes ####
```

or

```
# one hash and four (or more) equals ====
```

and if you use two hashes at the start it indents but this behaves strangely, sometimes causing indenting of various (single-starting-hash) bookmarks beneath it, and I'm not sure why. (please weigh in if you know!)

```
## example ####
```

Spaces don't matter

```
##example####
```

Bookmarks can be accessed via the bottomleft dropdown in BobC's answer, or in the top right Document Outline, next to source, CTRL+SHIT+O.